# Use limit after join

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a problem with pagination in codeigniter 3. I must use $this->db->limit after join and 2 where. I post my code here...

**Model**

```
  public function fetch_matching_candidati_by_posizione($limit, $start, $event_id, $id_competenza)
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('matching_candidati');
    $this->db->join('competenze_candidato', 'competenze_candidato.id_candidato = matching_candidati.id_candidato');
    $this->db->where('competenze_candidato.id_competenza', $id_competenza);
    $this->db->where('matching_candidati.event_id', $event_id);  
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
      return $query->result();
    }else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**Controller**

```
public function cerca_candidati_per_posizione()
{
    if($this->getUtente()->isAdmin())
    {    
        $event_id = $this->uri->segment(6);
        $event_anno = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $event_url = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $id_competenza = trim($this->input->post('posizione_digital_job_id'));

        $this->load->model('matching_candidati_model');
        $matching_candidati_model = new matching_candidati_model();
        $this->load->model('matching_competenze_model');
        $matching_competenze_model = new matching_competenze_model();                

        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "amministratore/eventi/".$event_anno."/".$event_url."/matching/".$event_id."/candidati_posizioni_aperte/cerca_candidati_per_posizione";

        if($id_competenza == "Altro"){
            $config["total_rows"] = $matching_candidati_model->record_count_by_id_posizione_altro($event_id);
        }else{
            $config["total_rows"] = $matching_candidati_model->record_count_by_id_posizione($event_id, $id_competenza);
        }

        $config["per_page"] = 50;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 9;
        $config['num_links'] = 2;

        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';

        $config['first_link'] = '&laquo; First';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $config['next_link'] = 'Next &rarr;';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Previous';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(9)) ? $this->uri->segment(9) : 0;

        if($id_competenza == "Altro"){
            $data_pass["candidati"] = $matching_candidati_model->fetch_matching_candidati_by_posizione_altro($config["per_page"], $page, $event_id);
            $data_pass['numero_candidati'] = $matching_candidati_model->record_count_by_id_posizione_altro($event_id);
        }else{
            $data_pass["candidati"] = $matching_candidati_model->fetch_matching_candidati_by_posizione($config["per_page"], $page, $event_id, $id_competenza);
            $data_pass['numero_candidati'] = $matching_candidati_model->record_count_by_id_posizione($event_id, $id_competenza);
        }

        $data_pass["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data_pass['event_id'] = $event_id;
        $data_pass['event_anno'] = $event_anno;
        $data_pass['event_url'] = $event_url;
        $data_pass['competenze'] = $matching_competenze_model->get_all_competenze_default();         

        $data_header=array('title'=>'Master Club - Home Amministratore',
            'css'=>array('bootstrap.css', 'bootstrap-responsive.css'),
            'js'=>array('jquery.js', 'bootstrap.js', 'bootstrap.min.js',
            'bootstrap-dropdown.js', 'bootstrap-button.js', 'bootstrap-alert.js',
            'bootstrap-collapse.js', 'bootstrap-tooltip.js', 'bootstrap-transition.js', 'bootstrap-tab.js'));
        $breadcrumps=array(
            '0'=>'Home',
            '1'=>'Amministratore',
            '2'=>'Eventi',
            '3'=>$event_anno,
            '4'=>$event_url,
            '5'=>'Candidati job matching'
        );
        $data_header['breadcrumps']=$breadcrumps;
        $url_breadcrumps=array(
            '0'=>'amministratore/login',
            '1'=>'amministratore/home',
            '2'=>'amministratore/eventi',
            '3'=>'amministratore/eventi/'.$event_anno,
            '4'=>'amministratore/eventi/'.$event_anno.'/'.$event_url,
            '5'=>'amministratore/eventi/'.$event_anno.'/'.$event_url.'/matching/'.$event_id.'/candidati_posizioni_aperte'
        );
        $data_header['url_breadcrumps']=$url_breadcrumps;

        $data_footer['filtri'] = true;

        $this->load->view('header', $data_header);
        $this->load->view('amministratore/matching/matching/candidati_posizioni_aperte', $data_pass);
        $this->load->view('footer', $data_footer);

    }
    else
    {
        show_error('Accesso negato', 403);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Can someone help me?
If i switch on page 2 of the list dont show nothing...

Comment: You probably have the error in your controller, where you init the config for your pagination. Can you add your controller code?

Comment: 1. You should edit your question to add your code and not answer. 
2. Are you sure that the uri->segment(9) is your pagination?

Comment: yes this->uri->segment(9) is correct.

Comment: return 50/100/150...

Comment: In your model, add $this->db->last_query() after $query = $this->db->get(); to check the sql.

Comment: ok i will try now

Comment: "SELECT * FROM (`ext_matching_candidati`) JOIN `ext_competenze_candidato` ON `ext_competenze_candidato`.`id_candidato` = `ext_matching_candidati`.`id_candidato` WHERE `ext_competenze_candidato`.`id_competenza` = '' AND `ext_matching_candidati`.`event_id` = '162' LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50" This is the result

Comment: oh.... the problem is in $id_competenza right

Comment: Ok the "$id_competenza" was the problem. Thank you for help man!

Comment: Glad you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this makes a difference but remove your "from" and change your get to `$this->db->get('matching_candidati')->result();`

Yo don't need your check down below because

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $query->result();
}else {
  return false;
}
```

It's repetitive assuming you'll be checking to see if the query returns false. When if you just check query result set in general you will get true if there are results and false if it is empty

so in your view it would be:

```
if(candidati){

  //rest of your view action
}
```